# What does "all" mean in meta robots tag?

Tags: meta-robots

Several websites have the following [meta tag aimed at search engines](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html) like Google, Bing, etc.:

```
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
```

What does it do?

Comment: A related question was asked recently that ended up covering similar gound: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47770/which-meta-robots-tag-gets-preference - notable is [John Meullers comment](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47770/which-meta-robots-tag-gets-preference#comment47602_47798), "the 'positive' ones (all, index, follow) have no effect at all."

Comment: @w3d, agreed — should make the asterisked part more prominent in [my answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/48154/19629)?

Comment: See also: [Which meta "robots" tag gets preference?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/47770/17633)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is more or less [the same as writing](http://www.metatags.org/meta_name_robots):

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
```

Interestingly, the `"all"` variant is [not actually suggested by Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812) as an alternative, but it works* nonetheless.

Either command (when placed in the `<head>` section of your HTML code) tells search engines to index the page the tag is on, as well as crawl all other pages that are being linked to from that location.*

---

<sup>* That, however, is the default behaviour of search engine spiders — so the necessity of adding the either `"all"` or `"index, follow"` on pages [has been questioned](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/get-rid-of-the-meta-name-robots-content-index-follow-tag.695/) on [multiple ocassions](http://www.seomoz.org/q/meta-name-robots-content-index-follow).</sup>

<sub>N.B. The other commands, `"noindex"` and `"nofollow"`, are very useful.</sub>